# Transforming UIImage in Circular Motion without changing angle + Cocoa

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, transform, quartz-2d

I want to transform/rotate an UIImage in circular motion without changing the angle of the image. Following diagram explains the requirement.
[image]
How this can be done using UIView transform property. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you only need to use the UIView frame property. However, because you are taking a non-linear path between your source and destination you will likely have to dabble with CoreAnimation.

Check out [CAKeyFrameAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAKeyframeAnimation) to animate a property through an arbitrary key path.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanx for answer. Can you plz elaborate in detail or any reference.

Comment: I need another help related to this. The thing is that I want to rotate the Circle & the 'Label' at the same time. I can rotate them individually, but I want to combine these both & should rotate concurrently. How should I do this. I read about 'CAAnimationGroup', but I have two different layers/Views & also I placed the both code one below another, but no concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

My book provides sample code for animating an image along a path:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#FIGnancyBell

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
// ... define the path using CGPath... functions ...
CAKeyframeAnimation* anim1 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim1.path = path;
```

Comment: I need another help related to this. The thing is that I want to rotate the Circle & the 'Label' at the same time. I can rotate them individually, but I want to combine these both & should rotate concurrently. How should I do this. I read about 'CAAnimationGroup', but I have two different layers/Views & also I placed the both code one below another, but no concurrency.

Comment: There is no "circle" in your original question. Ask a separate question, describing more correctly and specifically what you want to do and showing what code you have tried.

Comment: Here "Circle" refers to the circular image in which label "ABC" is placed. Now currently both label "ABC" & "Circle" are moving i.e. Transforming but no concurrently. The time interval set for both is same. I have taken the reference of the code provided by in ur book. Its working, but I want concurrency.

Comment: Code can't be shown in a comment. Do what I suggested: ask a new question. That way you and your answers can show code. When you show your code, someone will be able to tell you why it isn't concurrent.